# how switch to previous version in n (Node version manager)?

Tags: javascript, npm, nvm, n

Basically, I installed `n(tj/n)`for managing my node versions, and after that I installed a node version 14.6, it automatically switched my node version to 14.6 and also try to switch my version using `n` command but that shows only the one that I installed with `n`.

So, is there any way to switch to my main node version (that's installed previously) ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if n preserves your current node version, but if you know your previous version e.g. 12.13.0 just type

`n 12.13.0`

It will install and switch to 12.13.0. After the installation you can switch versions just running `n`.

Comment: yeah !! that is a solution also !!

Comment: answer: https://github.com/tj/n/issues/733